# While implementing 'if' condtion getting an erorr- float object has no attribute 'mean'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement an adjustment in the dataset by imputing mean and standard deviation using an if else condition. However i am getting an stating "float object has no attribute 'mean'

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# define the input data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Inv_InvAmt_GC":[   51447.3851, 3098097.358,    12746.6057, 960663.2583,    22847.3364, 63226.4458, 29078.7812, 22762.183,  86131.875,  1258.8596,  1125.54,    6461.9148,  31501.0519, 434364.4329,    49069.9112, 1327.4046,  960663.2583,    22847.3364, 63226.4458, 29078.7812, 22762.183,  86131.875,  1258.8596,  1125.54,    6461.9148,  31501.0519, 434364.4329,    49069.9112, 1327.4046],
"Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC":[    14520.366,  2072241.361,    5622.3136,  279503.5,   6401.4157,  15898.5926, -522.1417,  2095.0637,  86131.875,  0,  584.1,  1594.4148,  1324.7325,  0,  7684.9846,  1327.4046,  279503.5,   6401.4157,  15898.5926, -522.1417,  2095.0637,  86131.875,  0,  584.1,  1594.4148,  1324.7325,  0,  7684.9846,  1327.4046],
"Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC":[ 36927.0191, 1025855.996,    7124.2921,  681159.7583,    16445.9207, 47327.8532, 29600.9229, 20667.1193, 0,  1258.8596,  541.44, 4867.5, 30176.3194, 434364.4329,    41384.9266, 0,  681159.7583,    16445.9207, 47327.8532, 29600.9229, 20667.1193, 0,  1258.8596,  541.44, 4867.5, 30176.3194, 434364.4329,    41384.9266, 0],
"group":[   2,  1,  0,  2,  2,  1,  2,  0,  1,  1,  2,  1,  2,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  2,  0,  1,  2,  1,  2,  2,  1],
"market":[  "UK",   "UK",   "UK",   "UK",   "UK",   "UK",   "UK",   "china",    "china",    "china",    "china",    "china",    "china",    "china",    "china",    "china",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India",    "India"]

})

def cluster(x,y,a,b):
        if x==2 and y=='UK':
            if((a>a.mean()&(b>b.mean()+b.std())):
                return 1
            else: return 2
        if x==2 and y=='china':
            if((a>a.mean())&(b>b.mean()+b.std())):
                return 1
            else: return 2
        if x==0 and y=='India':
            if((a>a.mean())&(b>b.mean()+b.std())):
                return 2
            else: return 0
               
df['cluster_new']=df.apply(lambda x:cluster(x['group'],x['market'],x["Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC"],x["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"]),axis=1)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Comment: you need to calculate `mean` and `std` outside the function because in `df.apply` function  you pass `axis = 1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.` so a single value or a `row` not the entire `column` passed in `cluster` function. So you can't calculate `mean` and `std`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible answer to your problem. I have edited my answer to include country wise mean,std. This is not efficient if you have many different countries. But for this problem it will work

```
df_uk = df.query('market=="UK"')
df_china = df.query('market=="china"')
df_india = df.query('market=="India"')

a_mean_uk =df_uk["Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC"].mean()
a_mean_china =df_china["Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC"].mean()
a_mean_india =df_india["Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC"].mean()
b_mean_uk = df_uk["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"].mean()
b_mean_china = df_china["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"].mean()
b_mean_india = df_india["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"].mean()
b_std_uk = df_uk["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"].std()
b_std_china = df_china["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"].std()
b_std_india = df_india["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"].std()

def cluster(x,y,a,b):
    if x==2 and y=='UK':
        if((a>a_mean_uk) &(b>b_mean_uk+b_std_uk)):
            return 1
        else: return 2
    if x==2 and y=='china':
        if((a>a_mean_china)&(b>b_mean_china+b_std_china)):
            return 1
        else: return 2
    if x==0 and y=='India':
        if((a>a_mean_india)&(b>b_mean_india+b_std_india)):
            return 2
        else: return 0

df['cluster_new']=df.apply(lambda x:cluster(x['group'],x['market'],x["Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC"],x["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"]),axis=1)
```

Comment: a_mean is considering the complete market mean however i would need only the mean of UK and the standard deviation of UK to impute the  cluster_new basis on the group

Comment: I believe that applies to every if else condition..let me modify the code little bit

Answer (score 1):

`x["Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC"]` is the value of row, you may want the whole column by passing `df["Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC"]`.

In this case, you need to get the original `a` and `b` by index.

```py
def cluster(row, x,y,a,b):
        if x==2 and y=='UK':
            if((a.iloc[row.name]>a.mean())&(b.iloc[row.name]>b.mean()+b.std())):
                return 1
            else: return 2
        if x==2 and y=='china':
            if((a.iloc[row.name]>a.mean())&(b.iloc[row.name]>b.mean()+b.std())):
                return 1
            else: return 2
        if x==0 and y=='India':
            if((a.iloc[row.name]>a.mean())&(b.iloc[row.name]>b.mean()+b.std())):
                return 2
            else: return 0

df['cluster_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: cluster(x, x['group'],x['market'],df["Inv_InvAmtLatePay_GC"],df["Inv_InvAmtOnTime_GC"]),axis=1)
```